# Pandas is string in Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to pull the column "Genre" and check for the input string.  If the input is in that column return all rows with that keyword.   Kind of new to this. Tried everything. including .isin

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

movie_list = pd.read_csv ('https://datasets.imdbws.com/title.basics.tsv.gz', low_memory= False, delimiter= "\t", names=["Const", "Type", "Title", "Alt", "Adult", "Start", "End", "Run", "Genre"], usecols= ["Title", "Adult", "Start", "Run", "Genre"])

print("Hello\n\n")


def Choose():
    print("Choose an Option\n\n1: Search by Title\n\n2: Choose Categories\n\n3: Random Selection\n")
    choice = input()
    if choice == "1":
        title = input("Enter your title.\n\n")
        print (movie_list.loc[movie_list["Title"] == title])
    if choice == "2":
        genre_exists = 0
        while genre_exists < 1:
            genre = input("\nChoose a Genre:\n\n")
            if genre in movie_list["Genre"]:
                print (movie_list.loc[movie_list["Genre"] == genre])
                genre_exists += 1
                break
            else:
                print("Try Again")
                continue
```

Comment: What if you try `if genre in movie_list["Genre"].unique():` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `if genre in movie_list["Genre"]:` will return `False` because movie_list["Genre"] is of type `pd.Series` and doesn't have the same behavior as an array. For example, `"a" in pd.Series(["a"])` will return `False` as well.

Instead you can try `if genre in movie_list["Genre"].unique():` which will work as expected because `movie_list["Genre"].unique()` is a numpy array.

Another alternative would be `if movie_list.Genre.str.contains(genre).any()` since that will return `True` as long as any row contains genre.

Sample output:

```
>>> Choose()
Choose an Option

1: Search by Title

2: Choose Categories

3: Random Selection

2

Choose a Genre:

Animation,Short
                                        Title Adult Start Run            Genre
2                      Le clown et ses chiens     0  1892   5  Animation,Short
4                                 Un bon bock     0  1892  12  Animation,Short
15                        Autour d'une cabine     0  1894   2  Animation,Short
231             Choque de dos transatlánticos     0  1899   2  Animation,Short
249                        Matches: An Appeal     0  1899   1  Animation,Short
...                                       ...   ...   ...  ..              ...
8317111        EverQuest II Lore in a Minute!     0  2014  \N  Animation,Short
8317161      EverQuest Next Lore in a Minute!     0  2014  \N  Animation,Short
8317162  DC Universe Online Lore in a Minute!     0  2014  \N  Animation,Short
8317167       Dark Souls II Lore in a Minute!     0  2014  \N  Animation,Short
8317181            Diablo 3 Lore in a Minute!     0  2014  \N  Animation,Short

[33734 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: This worked flawlessly, thanks!   I was not aware of the .any() option until today.

Comment: You're welcome - by the way, If you found my answer helpful, please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), thank you!